# SSRS Report repeated X number of times per page based on passed in list

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have created a based report that uses a stored proc and takes a single ID value to then display its data.

I would like to give a "print report" a list of these ID values and have it repeat the report 3 times per page, each report displaying data from a different ID.

I have tried using a [subreport] inside of a [table] as one of the [datarows] but i am not sure how to get it to repeat 3 times per page based on giving it an array of [IDs]

Do I need a second query on the table that takes some kind of temp table ID list?

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.IDList
AS TABLE
(
  ID INT
);
GO
```

How do I pass that to the subreport so it makes the 3 per page part?

Comment: Are you doing this because you're having trouble with multi-valued parameters?  If so, consider not using subreports, and instead using a single report with [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2866/sql-server-reporting-services-using-multivalue-parameters/) strategy.  The main difference is that you would make each cell about 1/3 the size of the page and insert a rectangle, and then otherwise place in that rectangle what you would have placed in your subreport.

Comment: I don't think so.   The idea here is... think of it like a concert ticket.  1 person buys 5 tickets.  the tickets have set areas where name and number and concert name go on the ticket.   There is room for 3 tickets per printed page.  so the last two (of 5) tickets have to be printed on page 2.  The report is a set number of fields in a very specific layout so as to fit onto ticket print areas.  hence why i was looking at a sub-report (which would be the individual ticket report form)

Comment: Have you tried adding multiple detail sections to the report. Each detail section will have the same information and each page will have the 3 details. Make sure the 3 detail section do not over run to next page